# Copy data from a SpreadSheet to another based on filtered range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this script that copy the entire content from source spreadsheet to the target spreadsheet.
But I would to copy only a specific column (Col B) dependent form another column (Col C) with the content "Italy".

```
function CopyDataToNewFile() {
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1jtZli...'); // sss = source spreadsheet
  var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Sorgente'); // ss = source sheet
  //Get full range of data
  var SRange = ss.getDataRange();
  //get A1 notation identifying the range
  var A1Range = SRange.getA1Notation();
  //get the data values in range
  var SData = SRange.getValues();

  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('185I...'); // tss = target spreadsheet
  var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Destinazione'); // ts = target sheet
  //set the target range to the values of the source data
  ts.getRange(A1Range).setValues(SData);

}
```

I have reached this conclusion. There is a method in the destination sheet (where there is the data validation from the source sheet) where the data validation display only the value not inserted yet in the destination sheet?

Comment: i have tried with this code but it takes from the sourcesheet all the columns. I need only Col B dependent from Col C with the value "Italy" inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function CopyDataToNewFile() {
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1jtZli...'); 
  var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Sorgente');
  var SRange = ss.getDataRange();
  var A1Range = SRange.getA1Notation();
  var SData = SRange.getValues();
  var B=[];
  SData.forEach(function(r){
    if(r[2]=='Italy') {
      B.push([r[1]]);
    }
  });
  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('185I...');
  var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Destinazione');
  ts.getRange(1,1,B.length,1).setValues(B);
}
```

Here's a couple of ways that you can play with.  I think the first one will be much faster.

The first one get's data all at one and writes output data all at one time.

```
function Copy() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('source spreadsheet id')
  var ssh=ss.getSheetByName('sorg');
  var dss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('destination spreadsheet id')
  var dsh=dss.getSheetByName('dest')
  var srg=ssh.getRange(1,1,ssh.getLastRow(),ssh.getLastColumn());
  var svA=srg.getValues();
  var oA=[];
  svA.forEach(function (r,i) {
    if (r[2]=='Italy') {
      oA.push([r[1]]);
    }
  });
  dsh.getRange(dsh.getLastRow()+1,1,oA.length,1).setValues(oA);
}
```

The second one get column B and the column C and compares each row of column C with the string 'Italy' if column C equals "Italy" then in appends that same row of column B so it does a lot more writes and one more read.

```
function Copy() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('source spreadsheet id');
  var ssh=ss.getSheetByName('sorg');
  var dss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('destination spreadsheet id');
  var dsh=dss.getSheetByName('dest');
  var srgB=ssh.getRange(1,2,ssh.getLastRow());//col B
  var srgC=ssh.getRange(1,3,ssh.getLastRow());//col C
  var BvA=srgB.getValues();
  var CvA=srgC.getValues();
  var oA=[];
  BvA.forEach(function (r,i) {
    if(CvA[i][0]=='Italy') {
      dss.appendRow([BvA[i][0]]);
    }
  });  
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. And instead the Col C, there is another Col? Example Col P?

Comment: Assuming your range starts at column A and includes col P then it would be `r[15]` Column Number - 1;

Comment: And if i change Col B with another? Example Col A?

Comment: `B.push([r[0]]);`

Comment: Ok. Last question. Where i set to start with pasting to the destination sheet? Example from Col B?

Comment: the problem is this. when i paste into destination sheet for the first time, there is no problem, if then always into destination sheet i filter the columns and then I re-activate the function, there is no correspondency between the column pasted and the columns adjacent into destination sheet.

Comment: The first one is not a good solution cause it replicates anytime the same values already pasted with a previous activation. The second one not works and gives in the source sheet strings like these: [Ljava.lang.Object;@83f148
[Ljava.lang.Object;@3bbe4766

Comment: Try the second one again I made a smallchange

Comment: I don't understand what your saying about the first one.

Comment: Tried but it paste on the source sheet.

Comment: Oh may be what you're saying is that you want this `dsh.getRange(dsh.getLastRow()+1,1,oA.length,1).setValues(oA);` to be this `dsh.getRange(1,1,oA.length,1).setValues(oA);`

Comment: I would need to  see an image of the sheets involved and perhaps you can supply some csv data.  It's a whole lot easier to troubleshoot a problem with [mcve]

Comment: It's just last line.  The whole code won't fit into a comment.